# how can i add mouse down event on picture control in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mouseevent, image

i want indentify all mouse click event like WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP, on picture control in vc++,

but i am not able to do this

please tell me how can i identifies all events separately.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to sub-class the control to see those messages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window

Comment: @CodyGray: thanks for your replay but i am very new in vc++ please can you give any hint or any example? because i don't know how and where should i use this WM_*BUTTON*  messages.

Comment: You'll need to get a book that teaches you how to program in C++ using the Win32 API. That's not something an answer on SO can teach you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event handler to the picture control using Visual Studio IDE and modify the code for handler function. That should be easy.

I'm guessing you're using MFC. In that case you have to add an activex control to your dialog. 
i. **Adding the control:** To add such a control to your dialog box right click your dialog box and click the option called "Insert ActiveX Control". A modal dialog box appears. You have to select "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Image". Click OK. Control is added.
ii. **Select an image:** Right click your newly added control and select "Properties". Select your desired image clicking the picture attribute. Also there are other properties to customize the picture i.e, stretching, clipping image etc. You'll see your image is loaded into the control.
iii. **Adding the handler function:** Right click the control and select "Add Event handler". From the new modal dialog box select "MouseDown" or "MouseUp" as message type and click "add and edit". Add your code to achieve desired behavior.

N.B: MFC is not available with Visual C Express. You need a professional version of VS to compile MFC code.

Comment: Uhhh... How does this work, exactly? What does the "handler function" look like for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and friends?

Comment: I see... I wasn't assuming that he was using MFC. The question doesn't say that anywhere. This is also the wrong solution. There's absolutely no reason to use an ActiveX control just to handle mouse events.

Comment: @CodyGray, I know using the API or deriving a picture control class is the best option.

Anyway, I just posted one of the many solutions to make it easier for OP.

Answer (score 2):

You should enable property "Notify" of PictureControl to get the event.